# Calculating AGE in completed in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a date of birth variable in my dataset, however, the reference date 2FEB2022 is not in the dataset and I would like to calculate age. How do you calculate age in completed years?

Comment: Include the reference date as a literal date, `'02FEB2022'd`, in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be something like this, although I haven't got SAS in front of me to test so I may have got the syntax slightly wrong:

```
AGE=INTCK('YEAR',DateOfBirth,'02FEB2022'd,'C');
```